# app's designed area

Tags: iphone, app-store

The Apple guidelines say:

> Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

What is their designed container area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it means that you should not write or read data to/from any other directory other than your own applcations directory.

e.g. you can update the sqlite DB of your another app from your own app unless there is a public API that allows that

Comment: In some cases, apps developed by the same company/person are allowed to edit the other application's directory.

Comment: In what cases this would not be allowed? Have you were done this? How would Review team get to know that our App accesses the data from another app?

Answer (score 2):

Each Application is bound by its directory where it is installed. Apple restricts you from accessing the contents of another App through its directory from your App.